# SCSS mixins not working as expected for Foundation overrides

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I am importing foundation components individually as I use them but am having a hard time customizing the foundation global variables in an organized fashion.

I have a `foundation-components.scss` file where I import and include all of my necessary components. This is how it looks:

```
// foundation-components.scss
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
@import '../assets/fonts/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css';
@include foundation-global-styles;
@include foundation-grid;
@include foundation-button;
@include foundation-button-group;
@include foundation-forms;
@include foundation-visibility-classes;
@include foundation-close-button;
@include foundation-tooltip;
```

Now I try adding some customization to be included in mixins so that I can leave my file organized such as:

```
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
@import '../assets/fonts/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css';

@mixin custom-foundation-settings {
    $tooltip-background-color: white;
}

@mixin foundation-components {
    @include foundation-global-styles;
    @include foundation-grid;
    @include foundation-button;
    @include foundation-button-group;
    @include foundation-forms;
    @include foundation-visibility-classes;
    @include foundation-close-button;
    @include foundation-tooltip;
}

@include custom-foundation-settings
@include foundation-components
```

This does not work. But if I define the `$tooltip-background-color: white` globally, it does. This works:

```
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
@import '../assets/fonts/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css';

$tooltip-background-color: white;

@mixin foundation-components {
    @include foundation-global-styles;
    @include foundation-grid;
    @include foundation-button;
    @include foundation-button-group;
    @include foundation-forms;
    @include foundation-visibility-classes;
    @include foundation-close-button;
    @include foundation-tooltip;
}

@include foundation-components;
```

Why? I don't understand why putting the custom variable inside of a mixin does not work.

Comment: Order of inheritance. What if you move `@mixin custom-foundation-settings` down below `@mixin foundation-components` so they're actually loaded before it's called?

Comment: But my `custom-foundation-settings` includes a variables that is used inside of the foundation-tooltip which is included inside of the foundation-components mixin. Therefore I need to call it before. You can see in my second block of text that it does work when i declare the variable globally before the mixin.